# Struts 2 iterate enum

Tags: java, jsp, enums, struts2

Is it possible in Struts 2 to iterate an enum using the tag `<s:iterator>`?
Right now I'm doing it using a list of String, but is it possible to use an enum directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. It is a bit ugly, the answer is enable static method access, use inner class syntax for the OGNL expression (uses the '$'), both in conjunction will let you then get at the values method as already mentioned by Steven. Here is an example:

**Example Action**:

```
package com.action.test;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class EnumTest extends ActionSupport{
    enum Numbers{ONE, TWO, THREE};
}
```

**Example JSP**:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Enum Test</h1>
        //NOTE THE USE OF THE $ character to access the inner class on the following two lines.
        length: <s:property value="@com.action.test.EnumTest$Numbers@values().length"/><br/>
        <s:iterator value="@com.action.test.EnumTest$Numbers@values()">
            <s:property/><br/>
        </s:iterator> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**:

---

## Enum Test

length: 3
ONE
TWO
THREE

---

**Note**: Ensure that static method access is enabled. Simple way to do this is to add the following after the `<struts>` tag in struts.xml.

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Sort of. You can't iterate an enum directly because its not a collection of values (an enum reference just represents one of the enum constants). However, you can iterate the `values()` method of the enum, which is an array, or you can create an `EnumSet` in your action and iterate that.

### Example Enum

```
package example;

public enum SomeEnum {
  ONE, TWO, THREE;

  /* I don't recall if/how you can refer to non-getters in OGNL. */
  public String getName() {
    return name();
  }
}
```

### Example JSP

```
<s:iterator value="@example.SomeEnum@values()">
  <s:property value="name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: +1 for the first correct solution, I so typically put enums inside my classes that accessing an inner class would be a requirement. If the OP creates his enums as regular classes (I mean not inner classes) then this is definitely the right solution. PS: to access a non getter just add () to the end.

Comment: I thought so, but adding `()` wasn't working for me. Oh well.