# Struts2 accessing enum from JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2, enums, ognl

I have the following class

```
package com.test;

public class SomeClass {
   public enum COLOR {RED,BLUE}
}
```

I want to access values of `COLOR` enum in my JSP. I've tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
<s:property value="@com.test.SomeClass.COLOR@RED"/>
<s:property value="@com.test.SomeClass@COLOR.RED"/>
```

Any body came across this issue before?
[I've already enabled static method access in struts.xml]

Comment: you can do that but you need to enable `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true`

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708594/struts-2-iterate-enum

Comment: This question and that one should be merged. The title of this question is clearer but effectively they require the same solution.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi i've already enabled that.But can't seem to be able to access the enum

Comment: @DevBlanked: have u looked at the link i posted here

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi thanks for the link. I see that trick is to use '$' mark to refer nested classes.

Comment: @DevBlanked: yes, you need to use `$`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `enum`-s there is not need to enable `static method access`.

Enum-s can be accessed using `@` sign like that:

```
<s:property value="@package.ENUM@enumvalue"/>
```

In your case since you are declaring `enum` inside class use `$` sign to refer to your `enum`.

```
<s:property value="@com.test.SomeClass$COLOR@RED"/>
```

Comment: I wish I'd have come across this answer weeks ago. The `$` is what I was missing since my `enum`s are declared inside other classes.