# jqGrid select not populated with data from Struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

Once again I'm stuck using the `jqGrid`in `Struts2` with `struts2-jquery plugin`. This time I wanted to put a `<select/>`field in the search dialog for a column, as done in this tutorial [here.](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SearchGrid#A_Grid_Column_with_Select_Box_in_the_search_dialog)

I built and tested the action supposed to return JSP with the select and all populated values inside of it and it works fine, I think the issue relates fully to `jqGrid`. Maybe I'm overlooking something here.

When I open the search popup and select the column I want to search for (the one with the `select` set), it triggers the action which retrieves the data and then a `select` input appears but with no data inside it, it appears to be null, so I have an empty `select`.

Below I'm posting some of my code:

**jqGrid global config:**

```
 <sjg:grid
        id="resGrid"
        altRows="false"
        caption="%{getText('reservationTable.title')}"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        editurl="%{deleteUrl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="10,15,30"
        rowNum="15"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorSearch="true"
        autowidth="true"
        navigatorAdd="false"
        onDblClickRowTopics="rowSelect"
        navigatorEdit="false"
        navigatorDelete="false"
        navigatorSearchOptions="{
                multipleSearch: true, 
                closeAfterSearch: true,
                afterRedraw: afterRedraw
        }"
        navigatorExtraButtons="{
                photos : { 
                        title : '%{getText('reservationTable.icon.photo')}', 
                        icon: 'ui-icon-image', 
                        onclick: showPhotos,
                        position: 'first'
                }
        }"
        >
```

**jqGrid column config:**

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="execution" 
index="execution" 
title="%{getText('execution')}" 
formatter="execution" 
search="true" 
searchtype="select" 
searchoptions="{ sopt:['eq'], 
                 dataUrl:'%{selecturl}', 
                 value: ':All;'}"/>
```

**Result from retrieving the data** (copied from the tutorial I linked above, this works fine):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<s:select list="executionStrValues" theme="simple" emptyOption="true"/>
```

I've been stuck with this for a couple of days and I made some research, I found that this script could be useful as in this link [HERE](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/515) this issue with jqGrid is discussed on Github. I used it like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    $.jgrid = {
            defaults : {
                ajaxSelectOptions: 'GET',
                async: false
            }
        }
})();
</script>
```

This other open issue relates to this topic aswell: [LINK](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/512)
I also saw some people suggest using the `formatter="select"`for the row, but if I understood correctly I don't need it because I'm not inline editing this column as [written in the documentation.](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select)

---

**UPDATE: ACTION CONFIGURATION**
Below my `<s:url>` which triggers the action returning values and the action's configuration:

`<s:url var="selecturl" action="getExecutionStatus" />`

**getExecutionStatus.action** where `ExecutionStatus` is an enum:

```
@ResultPath(value = "/")
public class UtilsAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3672057774005126256L;
    private List<String> executionStrValues;

    @Action(value="getExecutionStatus", results={
            @Result(name="success",location="jsp/selectExecution.jsp"),
            @Result(name="input", location="jsp/error.jsp"),
            @Result(name="login", location="index.jsp")
            })
    public String getExecutionValues(){

        List<ExecutionStatus> executionValues = Arrays.asList(ExecutionStatus.values());
        executionStrValues = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(ExecutionStatus ex: executionValues)
            executionStrValues.add(getText("executionStatus."+ex.toString()));


        return SUCCESS;

    }//getExecutionValues

    public List<String> getExecutionStrValues() {
        return executionStrValues;
    }

    public void setExecutionStrValues(List<String> executionStrValues) {
        this.executionStrValues = executionStrValues;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `selecturl` action class and configuration.

Comment: @AleksandrM any new thoguhts? I'm still stuck with this and have no idea what can be going wrong..

Comment: If your `ExecutionStatus` is an enum why do you need an action to fetch it? You can just use it in select tag - http://stackoverflow.com/q/16063819/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM because it's the way the jqgrid plugin works to populate a select inside a search field with that enum's values.. I don't really know another way to go around it

Answer (score 0):

put it your jsp page. i think it works.
`<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@taglib  prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but it's not working :(