# How to reference a variable in my action class from my jsp page

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I am using the struts  tag inside of a struts iterator tag to control what displays in one of my fields as follows.

```
<s:iterator value="commentViewList" >
  <s:if test="%{documentInfo.documentId != 0}">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center"><s:a href="%{documentLink}" tabindex="19"><s:text name="yes"/></s:a></div>  
  </s:if>

  <s:else>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center"><s:property value=""/></div>  
  </s:else>
```

It works fine but I would like to replace the 0 in the test with a reference to a noValueId int variable I have defined in my action page.  That will allow me to make one change if I ever need to change what I compare documentInfo.documentId to.  I use this value in my action page also.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also `documentInfo.documentId` is a variable from your Action class. You just need an attribute with its getter, or even only the getter. What's the problem ? :|

Comment: Originally I tried to reference a static variable (it was a static final constant) and when it didn't work I put the variable in a hidden field on my jsp page but that didn't help so I removed the hidden field.  I then read where you can't reference a static variable so I changed it to a non-static variable but it still didn't work but I had forgotten to put the hidden field back in.  As I was writing a response to your comment I realized what I had done so I put the hidden field back in and it works.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You can access static field. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16063819/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM So I can treat a static field just like an Enum?

Comment: You can access it like enum, using `@package.Class@FIELD`.

Comment: Thanks for the information!